# How bad are bad sectors?

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

How bad are bad sectors on a hard drive really? If a tool (e.g. disk utility from ubuntu/gnome) reports bad sectors on a disk, what is the expected time to death? (assuming the bad sector did not damage any existing files).

Comment: On second read one could understand _death of disk_ or _death of system by unbootability, or better written unavailability of boot capabilities_.

Comment: Related: [Bad Sectors on Hard Drive](http://superuser.com/q/152526/53590)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the file system format and the pace of physical degrading.

In case of traditional hard disk drives, since the Seagate Barracuda series arose circa ten years ago, I lost no disk because of bad sectors, but earlier than those disks I remember that already FAT32 and NTFS where enough good handling them.

So I would expect a very good support of bad sectors by FOSS file system formats and tools.

Comment: As long as the number of bad sectors doesn't grow… If it grows, then backup your data and replace the hard drive.